# Integrar fb no app ios swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Gente boa tarde tudo bom ?
Gostaria de saber se ao integrar o fb sdk no meu projeto ios swift se ao usuario logar  tenho acesso a lista de amigos dele ? 
E aproveitando a pergunta, alguem teria algum tutorial sobre a integração ? 
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegue sim, desde que ao fazer a autenticação com o Facebook você solicite a permissão `user_friends` para ter acesso a lista de amigos.

A request para pegar a lista de amigos é a seguinte:

```
let meRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: nil)
meRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   if (error != nil) {
       println(result) // Lista de amigos (paginada)
   } 
})
```

Um ótimo lugar para começar com a integração com a o SDK do Facebook, é a própria página deles: [Facebook SDK for iOS - Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Comment: Hmmm ok muito obrigado ... Irei ver